# Uncaught ReferenceError: dcount is not defined but working fine at other place

Tags: javascript

i have this javascript which i am trying to use at other place. i did console log at three places and at two places it is giving the desired result at third place it is throwing error.

Uncaught ReferenceError: dcount is not defined

you can see that same console log i have tried to print at three places. one at line no 21 with setTimeout and teo at line number  76 and 77. 76 is just dummy var which will print no doubt but 77 line is exactly same as line no 21 i.e     console.log(dcount.settings.style.customized.button_text);

i am confused which its giving undefined.

```
function testdata_pct() {

window.procountJs = window.procountJs || {}, procountJs.ProCount = function() {
   var dcount = {
        id: "procounter",
        shop: null,
        settings: {},
        block: {},
           patterns: {
            0: ["#047c8d", "#2ff289", "#ffffff", "#020610"],
            1: ["#401dba", "#825bf0", "#ffffff", "#401dba"],
            2: ["#ff4e6f", "#fb9168", "#ffffff", "#ff4e6f"]
            
        },
              
    };


setTimeout(function() {

  console.log(dcount.settings.style.customized.button_text);   // this one gives just fine outcome in console. same data is giving undefined in last para of code

}, 2000);
    
    
    

function r(e, a) {
        
        var t = new XMLHttpRequest;
        t.open("GET", e), t.responseType = "text", t.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"), a && (t.onload = function() {
            4 == t.readyState && 200 == t.status ? a(null, t.responseText) : a(t.status, t.responseText)
        }), t.send()
    }

function e() {

        return new Promise(function(n, e) {
            r("/index.json?q=" + dcount.id + "&view=pcount_down&cache=false", function(e, a) {
                var t = !1;
                null == e && (a = function(e) {
                    e = e.replace(/<!-[\S\s]*?-->/gm, "");
                    try {
                        return JSON.parse(e);
                    } catch (e) {
                    }
                }(a)) && (dcount.shop = a.metafields.shop, dcount.settings = a.metafields.settings, 0 == dcount.settings.charge && (dcount.settings.block_order = dcount.settings.block_order.slice(0, 1)), t = !0)
            })
        }
            

        )   
        
    
    }
    return {
    inituuuuu: function() {
            (function(e, a) {
                for (var t = 0; t < document.styleSheets.length; t++)
                    if (document.styleSheets[t].href == e) return;
                var n = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0],
                    r = document.createElement("link");
                r.rel = "stylesheet", r.type = "text/css", r.href = e, a && (r.onload = function() {
                    a()
                }), n.appendChild(r)
            })(dcount.cssUrl), window == window.top && e().then(function(e) {
                e 
            })
        }
    }
    
 }(), procountJs.ProCount.inituuuuu();
   
    var dummy = '999';
    
    console.log(dummy);  // this works just fine
    console.log(dcount.settings.style.customized.button_text);   // this gives error Uncaught ReferenceError: dcount is not defined

    
}   
    
 
setTimeout(function() {

 testdata_pct();

}, 2000);
```

any help will be great

Comment: Put it outside the scope

Comment: @bluejayke we tried putting them just before  closing of function but then  it is not even calling  }(), procountJs.ProCount.inituuuuu(); those setTimeout in last line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I could find two undefined problems

The first was at line 77, the console.log is out of the scope where dcount is defined.

The second at line 21

```
setTimeout(function() {

  console.log(dcount.settings.style.customized.button_text);   // this one gives just fine outcome in console. same data is giving undefined in last para of code

}, 2000);
```

The problem here, is not the dcount var, but the property settings.style (does not exists). If you are trying to add this property, maybe you are doing this just after try to read and, you should add it before read.

Comment: as i said this is coming from ajax call and it is giving expected log in line 21 so there is no doubt about its working or not. when we put it outside just before closing tag the setTimeout even not calling the console.log for dummy and others

Comment: But the problem is at line 77, right? Then is just out of the scope, because is out of the function that the dcount is defined... sorry if I am doing some misunderstanding here

Comment: we have edited the code now see if we add that outside then output is nil. nothing at all. https://stylishgames.myshopify.com/   check this link and console and js link is this    https://way2enjoy.com/shopify/1/countdowntimerpro/proxy/js/pct_11countaug26paidd20_free.js?shop=stylishgames.myshopify.com

Comment: this is because you put this after the return statement, then everything after the return statement inside the function will not be executed.

Comment: can u plz tell how to do. if we are doing after return statement no output. if we are doing just after return statement and calling then getting uncaught refrece error. any help will be great

Comment: for now, try this [the javascript](https://codepen.io/davidprof/pen/BaKjpej)

Comment: same error. i used ur code but same error u can see in console https://stylishgames.myshopify.com/

Comment: sorry, my mistake [can you verify this again?](https://codepen.io/davidprof/pen/BaKjpej), the function was never being called.

Comment: now no error but console says undefined https://stylishgames.myshopify.com/